# How to set multiple values on next row in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Row after last row with the data in the spreadsheet  `var nextRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getLastRow()+1;`

Five values
`var values = [[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5]];`

I want to add above five values in column A to E to next row and doing following does not work(Getting error: Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 993)  `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setActiveSelection("A:E"+ nextRow).setValues(values);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be safer to obtain the Range you want rather than setting and depending on a selection.

Your range specifier is `"A:E" + nextRow`, but should probably be `"A"+nextRow+":E"+nextRow`.  The former is likely giving you more than a single row.